# Disable IPv4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, ipv6, ipv4

I want to create a pure IPv6 environment or disable IPv4 completely, not just on the interface. If it is impossible, I want to disable IPv4 on boot via the command line or a configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make completely disabling ipv4 entirely impossible.
After a quick check on make menuconfig on kernel 4.4.189.
I could not find a way of disabling ipv4 without disabling the entire TCP/IP stack.
[image]

But you can disable IPv4 on interfaces with Network Manager:
To list the active connections:

> $ nmcli connection show --active

```
NAME     UUID                                               TYPE                     DEVICE 
Wired1   63e9c617-f3f8-416c-a40c-fbb460549169               802-3-ethernet           ens33
```

Modify the property of ipv4.method to disabled

> $ nmcli connection modify 63e9c617-f3f8-416c-a40c-fbb460549169
>   ipv4.method disabled

To apply the new settings. Let’s restart the networking:

> $ nmcli networking off
>
> $ nmcli networking on

Comment: I found the option, but then my laptop doesn't succeed in connecting at all...